# Regex may contain a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 2 kinds of data.

One data is something like this

```
ws=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
```

and the another data like this

```
ws=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9;utmz=111872281.1437151704.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
```

I wanna get the ws value, like

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
```

But i got problems for split the ";" character. Because sometime the data have the character, but sometimes it doesn't have that character.

I already tried using

```
ws=([^]*);?
```

and

```
ws=([^]*)[;?]
```

and I still doesn't get the correct data.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
/\bws=([^;]*)/
```

and grab captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL0pK1/1)

`([^;]*)` will match 0 or more of any character that is not `;`

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
ws=(.*?)(;|$)
```

Try it online: http://regexr.com/3bfbv

- `ws=` searches for that exact text
- `(` starts the matching group
- `.*?` searches for any characters, but **as few characters as possbile** ("non-greedy")
- `)` stops the matching group
- `(;|$)` searches for either a `;` or the end of the text (or the line)